# Add different button to list item to EDIT

Tags: 2013, list, custom-actions

Here's my newest situation:
The people I report to don't like the EDIT button on SharePoint list items, and want to create a new, custom button for people to edit list items.  They'll even accept a link (with custom text, like CLICK HERE, etc).

Here's what I've done so far:
In SPD, I've created a Custom Action in the list item menu.  This makes the option come up upon clicking the ellipsis.

But, is there a way to make this come up in the list in its own column, the same way the current edit or ellipsis does?

Answer (score 0):

You can Enable Context Menu on a Column using PowerShell.

```
#PowerShell to Enable Context Menu on a Column
#==============================================
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  
#Set Configuration Parameters
$webURL = "http://webUrl/"
$listName = "ListName"
$fieldName="ColumnName" #Display Name of the Field
  
#Get the Web, List, Item and User objects
$web= Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$list= $web.Lists[$listName]
  
#Get the column from List
$field = $list.Fields[$fieldName]
 
#Update Field Settings
$field.ListItemMenu = $True
$field.ListItemMenuAllowed = "Required"
$field.Update()
$list.Update()
```

Update:
You can do the same using SPD by updating the field like this.

```
<FieldRef Name="ColumnName" LinkToItem="TRUE" ListItemMenu="TRUE" />
```

Also, if you make "Title (linked to item with edit menu)" field available from list settings it should show the context menu.

Comment: I'd love to be able to - but I'm unable to use PS.  (not allowed)

Comment: You can do the same using SPD by updating the field like this. <FieldRef Name="ColumnName" LinkToItem="TRUE" ListItemMenu="TRUE" />

Comment: Also, if you make "Title (linked to item with edit menu)"  field available from list settings it should show the context menu